# Magento registration form

Tags: php, forms, magento, zend-framework, registration

I'm starting with magento and i'm trying to modify a template.
Right now the registration form has a first and last name and I want it to have only the first name.
I checked the code and I found something on a file "template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml" which has all fields for the form, but for the first and last name it has this piece of code:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_name')->setObject($this->getFormData())->setForceUseCustomerAttributes(true)->toHtml() ?>
```

Is there any file where I should setup the field of the registration form?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You need to navigate to template/customer/widget/name.phtml. If this doesn't exist in your theme, copy it from the default into the same folder structure.

You will find a `<div class="field name-lastname">` with the label and input that you can comment out.

Answer (score 0):

you can just set the div to style="display: none;"

and change the 'last name' input box's value to something like '_'